# Help me find the inverse measureable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inverse-function, measurable-functions

I am trying to understand measure theory and I have encountered the following question:

Let $\Omega=(1,2,3,4)$, $F=\{ \{ \emptyset\}\{ 1\} \{ 3\} \{ 1,3\}\{ 2,4\} \{ 1,2,4\} \{2,3,4\} \{ \Omega\} \}$,$ H=\{ \{ \emptyset\}\{ 1\} \{ 4\} \{ 1,4\}\{ 2,3\} \{ 1,2,3\} \{2,3,4\} \{ \Omega\} \}$

We have the following function map $f:\Omega -> \mathbb{R} $ such that $f=(-1)^n$. Decide whether f is measurable or not
with respect to F and H.

To do this I need to find the inverse function of f and see if  $f^{-1}(A)\in F $ For all $A \in H$ (and then the opposite case).

I get the inverse function to be  $f^{-1}(A)=-ln(A)$ which does not make sence since the logarithm of and integer is not likely to be an integer and therefore the preimage is pretty much never going to belong to F or H.

Any help would be massively apprichiated.

Comment: First of all $f^{-1}(A)$ is NOT the inverse function of $f$ taken on $A$, it is the preimage of $A$ under the mapping $f$. That is $f^{-1}(A) = \{ \omega \in \Omega \: | \: f(\omega) \in A \}$.

Comment: Here is a hint: Since $f$ can only take two values $-1$ and $1$ you really only need to consider $f^{-1}(\{-1\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{1\})$.